# How to address several datasets in a loop to perform a binary classification using a threshold value?

Tags: r, for-loop, binary

I'm relatively new in the R community (using RStudio) and am performing a study measuring the human gait. I'd like to set a threshold for the feet being on the floor (values >150) or oscilating (values <151). When feet lay on the ground the value should be changed to 1. Otherwise, I want to turn it to 0. This should be done to four of the five attributes - `pd`, `pi`, `td`, `ti` (all of these `integers`, as you can check on the code) - in each dataset: `k1`, `k2`, `k3`, `k4`.

I'd like to automate the process of classifying each measurement dataset. The classification itself works pretty good (the second `for` in the code below). The problem arises when trying to read each of the datasets (the first `for` in the code below). Specifically, by using the `k[j]` my intention is to switch between datasets k1, k2, k3 and k4. I think that using `k = c(ki, k2, k3, k4)` is not the appropiate way of addresing the different datasets, as `k` results in a "`List of 20`", and `k1`, `k2`, `k3` and `k4` are datasets of different length each (I cannot create a data frame due to incompatible lengths).

Of course a solution would be avoiding `k = c(k1,k2,k3,k4); for(j in 1:4){n = length(k[j]$Tiempo)}` and copypasting the rest of the code for each dataset. But I assume there might be more efficent ways of doing it!

**Here you are the code of the datset extraction (so that you can see the nature of its attributes)...**

```
k1 <- read_delim("Csv/kike1.csv", 
                 ";", escape_double = FALSE, col_types = cols(Tiempo = col_character(), 
                                                              `pd` = col_integer(), 
                                                              `pi` = col_integer(), 
                                                              `td` = col_integer(), 
                                                              `ti` = col_integer()), 
                 locale = locale(encoding = "WINDOWS-1252"), 
                 trim_ws = TRUE)
#There are four of these, one for each measurement.
```

**...and the code for the loops:**

```
k = c(k1,k2,k3,k4)
for(j in 1:4){
   n = length(k[j]$Tiempo)
      for(i in 1:n){
          if (k[j]$td[i]< 151){
                k[j]$td[i]=0
             }else{
                 k[j]$td[i]=1
             }
          if (k[j]$pd[i]< 151){
                k[j]$pd[i]=0
             }else{
                 k[j]$pd[i]=1
    }
    if (k[j]$ti[i]< 151){
      k[j]$ti[i]=0
    }else{
      k[j]$ti[i]=1
    }
    if (k[j]$pi[i]< 151){
      k[j]$pi[i]=0
    }else{
      k[j]$pi[i]=1
    }
  }
```

PD: When writing `k[j]$...` the assistive floating tag that shows up to select attributes (that follows the $ sign where I've written "...") just shows one attribute, which in fact changes in each of the lines where `k[j]$...`appears.

Finally I would like to plot it, but that's sorted out as you can see below. Suggestions are very welcome!

```
  ggplot(k[j])+
    ggtitle("Muestra 1") +
    geom_path(mapping = aes(Tiempo, td, colour = "Talón Derecho", group = 5))+
    geom_path(mapping = aes(Tiempo, pd, colour = "Puntera Derecha", group = 5)) +
    geom_path(mapping = aes(Tiempo, ti, colour = "Talón Izquierdo", group = 5)) +
    geom_path(mapping = aes(Tiempo, pi, colour = "Puntera Izquierda", group = 5))
}
```

I hope my first question has not been solved yet (I've spent quite a while extrapolating answers to similar questions but haven't made it so far) and having been clear enough :-).

**UPDATE**

As requested, here you are the sample!

```
>dput(head(k1))
structure(list(Tiempo = c("13:10:37.927", "13:10:37.927", "13:10:37.927", 
"13:10:37.927", "13:10:37.927", "13:10:37.927"), td = c(46L, 
903L, 903L, 903L, 903L, 904L), pd = c(256L, 457L, 458L, 457L, 
455L, 454L), ti = c(954L, 954L, 954L, 954L, 954L, 954L), pi = c(895L, 
895L, 895L, 895L, 895L, 895L)), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
    Tiempo = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), td = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector")), pd = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector")), ti = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector")), pi = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Btw, happy new year!

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(k1)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(k1, 20))`. Do all `k*` data sets have the same structure?

Comment: Take a look at `str(k)`. Your `k <- c(k1, k2, k3, k4)` is probably not doing what you think it is. A simpler approach would be to use `ifelse()` to recode your data and `lapply` to process the 4 separate data frames.

Comment: R is really good at transforming entire vectors (columns of data) all at once.  Using a for loop like this is not very idiomatic.  Post some sample data as @Rui Barradas suggested.